# objective-c: Assign variable instead of string inside array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string, variables

I would like to assign a variable instead of the string in my following code.
First i am creating an array from comma separated list of directories. Next for each directory in the array, i want to create them, if they doesn't exist.

How do i assign the directory from the array rather than: @"templates/standard1/css"
I have tried replacing it with s, but that didn't work out. I can NSlog the s, but it doesn't seem to create the directories.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *theString = @"templates, templates/standard1, templates/standard1/css, themes, themes/plain, themes/plain/384";
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *s in items) {
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"templates/standard1/css"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        // Directory does not exist so create it
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: WOW! How stupid was that?
Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @trumpetlicks you should answer the question so you can get the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the spaces are bothering your directories. You have each directory separated by ", " but are searching for "," (without a space). You can either take the spaces out of your `theString`, or use ", " as your separator, for using the string!!!

So either change

```
NSString *theString = @"templates, templates/standard1, templates/standard1/css, themes, themes/plain, themes/plain/384";
```

to this

```
NSString *theString = @"templates,templates/standard1,templates/standard1/css,themes,themes/plain,themes/plain/384";
```

Or Change this:

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

to this:

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

BUT NOT BOTH!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, Keep having fun :-)